# MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged & MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged events don't seem to trigger

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events, windows-phone-8, media-player

In the `PhoneApplicationLoaded` event I added the following code:

```
MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += StateSongChanged;
MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += StateSongChanged;
```

But the StateSongChanged procedure doesn't seem to tigger?

Does anyone know why this is, I'm fairly new to C# so it's probably something fairly simple.

In addition, this is the StateSongChanged block:

```
private void StateSongChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code
}
```

Comment: have you try with a breakPoint in 'StateSongChange()' ? your code never arrived in the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA Framework events are triggered after calling

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
```

so it's convenient to create IApplicationService class with timer, that calls FrameworkDispatcher.Update() over and over again.

For more info and how to read this:
[Enable XNA Framework Events in Windows Phone Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff842408.aspx)

Comment: Wow, I never knew simple things like events in the Xna framework were so hard to use! Thanks for the link, I'll get round to testing it soon.